# R: Ridge regression without glmnet

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I implemented a simpe ridge regression code based on the ridge regression formulas. 
Then I get some beta coefficients and then using the same dataset I tried it with *glmnet* but I got different results. I used just one lambda just for simplicity to see if the results will be correct. Here is the simple R code:

```
#Ridge regression 
set.seed(110)
n = 5
p = 2
x=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
y=as.matrix(rnorm(n))
int <- rep(1, length(y))
x <- cbind(int, x)
lambda=0.1
lambda.identity=lambda* diag(ncol(x))
beta_ridge=solve(t(x)%*%x+lambda.identity, t(x)%*%y)
beta_ridge

#using glmnet
library(glmnet)
fit=glmnet(x,y,alpha = 0, lambda = 0.1, standardize = FALSE)
coef(fit)
```

Here are the results:

```
    #without glmnet                       
              [,1]
    int  1.2318648
        -0.3213297
         0.7596814

     #with glmnet
                    s0
(Intercept)  1.3167044
V1          -0.3809595
V2           0.6795089
```

I didn't standardize the values so that I thought I would get the same output. I tried to work the *glmnet* code through but it was very complicated.

What could I be doing wrong in my code? I would very much appreciate any advice.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/129179/126864.

Comment: @WeihuangWong thanks I'm checking it